# Consolidating one sheet from each workbook in a folder into one workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task to consolidate a sheet from each workbook (the number of those might differ) from one folder into one master workbook.

Each workbook is based on a template so they look the same, each with two sheets.

I need one of those sheets, named "Fill this out", to be copied.

The result should be: Master data workbook, with as many worksheets as there are files in the folder, and each sheet containing data from the "Fill this out" sheet.

```vb
Sub MergeWorkbooks()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim File As String

FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Downloads\BH\"

File = Dir(FolderPath)

Do While File <> ""

    Workbooks.Open FolderPath & File
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Fill this out").Copy _
      after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = File
    Workbook.Close FolderPath & File
            
    File = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

This copies the first file and then error 400 pops out.

Additionally, the new sheet name is: "Fill this out" instead of file name.

Comment: There is at least one inconsistence: `Workbook.Close FolderPath & File` > `Workbook` is not a recognized function/command by VBA.

Comment: Hello @ALeXceL Originally my command was
`Workbook(File).Close`
But this in change gives me error: 
Compile Error: sub or function not defined.

Comment: Because `Workbook` don't exists in Excel VBA as an object or command. Its a variable Type. Sounds that you want to close that workbook: `Workbooks(File).Close savechanges:=False`

Comment: Always use 'Option Explicit' at the beginning of the code module so that the VBE flags this kind of problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to open the files in that folder, and close each one of them dismissing the respective save event. Note the `"*.xl*"` filter to only allow opening Excel files:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeWorkbooks()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim File As String

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Downloads\BH\"

    File = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    Do While File <> ""

        Workbooks.Open FolderPath & File
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Fill this out").Copy _
            after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = File
        Workbooks(File).Close savechanges:=False
            
        File = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

---

### EDIT

Try this modified code, which is more assertive dealing with the source workbooks (setting a Workbook object):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeWorkbooks()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim File As String
    Dim objWB As Excel.Workbook

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Downloads\BH\"

    File = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    Do While File <> ""

        Set objWB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & File)
       
        If Not objWB Is Nothing Then
            objWB.Worksheets("Fill this out").Copy _
                after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fill this out").Name = File
            objWB.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
   
        File = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. The workbook is not getting closed.
I get either error 400 or Application-defined or Object-defined error. 1004

Comment: Did you changed properly the code on VBE? Here it is running ok. Run the code with F8 (instead of F5) and when the code stops, click the 'Debug' button to see which line it fails. You can then inspect what is wrong, retrieving the values of passed variables, perhaps opening the Locals window, to get an overview of variables and objects.

Comment: Please take a look in my edited post.

Comment: Hello @ALeXcel 
I think I have found the source of problem :)
There is something wrong with the names of the documents. Once I altered name of the file it worked! Thank you so much!